# Laravel 5.2 custom middleware crashes localhost page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a middleware to check Authenticated user's Database and restrict them accessing routes. But when i apply the middleware to the routes the localhost page crashes.

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost redirected you too many times.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $user = \Auth::user();

        if (($user->plan == 'ip') && ($user->balance >= 1299)) {
            
            return $next($request);
            
        }
            return redirect('no_balance');

    
}
```

This is my route

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth','client','balance']],function(){

            Route::get('/no_balance',[
        'uses' => 'settingsController@noBalance',
        'as' => 'no_balance',

        ]);
});
```

Balance is the middleware code i have included above and without balance middleware the application works fine. BUt when i include balance middleware it throws the error.

My controller code

```
public function noBalance(){
    return view('no_balance')->with(compact('user_profiles','user_info'));
}
```

Comment: What does your route for 'no_balance' look like? The error would suggest you are getting caught in a redirect loop.

Comment: have edited the question kindly check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies here:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth','client','balance']],function(){

            Route::get('/no_balance',[
        'uses' => 'settingsController@noBalance',
        'as' => 'no_balance',

        ]);
});
```

Your `balance` middleware is checking `if (($user->plan == 'ip') && ($user->balance >= 1299))` and if they fail this then you are redirecting them to `'no_balance'` - which is also protected by this same middleware.

So you end up in a constant cycle of the middleware redirecting to `'no_balance'` and then the middleware redirecting you again.

To fix this, just remove the `'no_balance'` middleware from this route:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth','client']],function(){

            Route::get('/no_balance',[
        'uses' => 'settingsController@noBalance',
        'as' => 'no_balance',

        ]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this and it works. I hope it helps you. Instead of `return redirect('no_balance');` I use this: `abort(403,'Unauthorized action.');`
which loads the 403 view in views/errors/403